# How to do html5 validation then redirect to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I'm very new to this but I wanted to know how to make a button validate the inputs and then redirect to a page? I noticed that using the `onclick = ""` function validates the inputs with the appropriate input types e.g. email, tel. But I can't seem to make it so that it validates first before redirecting to the next page. It either it validates but doesn't redirect (it submits a form I think because the URL changes to like submit=?) or it just redirects to the next page without any validation

Button:

```
<button id ="button" class="subscribe btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Proceed to Payment</button>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "payment.html";
};
```

This currently doesn't do any validation at all just redirects it to the next page "payment.html" if I remove `"location.href = "payment.html";` it does the validation but never redirects. I'm guessing is that the default onclick function is the one that does the html5 validation and I think I want that to happen before I redirect to the next page.

I'm sorry if it was lengthy, I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: `<form ... novalidate> ... </form>` ?

Comment: do select the answer that worked for you so others having the same issue might also benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys sorry for the confusion!

I overlooked the form action tag to where i can just put the url to redirect to the next page. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well there are both options `html5` and `javascript`, you can use the `required` attribute in case you want to make any field compulsory and the for `action` attribute to submit the for to an action, for customized error messages you must use `javascript`, a simple demo for the validation and submitting the form is below for advanced examples and using javascript for validation using `regex` and other methods see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation)

```css
body {
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

form {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

p>label {
  display: block;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=number],
textarea,
fieldset {
  /* required to properly style form 
   elements on WebKit based browsers */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 90%;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input:invalid {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px red;
}

input:focus:invalid {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation -->

<form action="https://google.com">
  <p>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Title<abbr title="This field is mandatory">*</abbr></legend>
      <input type="radio" required name="title" id="r1" value="Mr"><label for="r1">Mr.</label>
      <input type="radio" required name="title" id="r2" value="Ms"><label for="r2">Ms.</label>
    </fieldset>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="n1">How old are you?</label>
    <!-- The pattern attribute can act as a fallback for browsers which
         don't implement the number input type but support the pattern attribute.
         Please note that browsers that support the pattern attribute will make it
         fail silently when used with a number field.
         Its usage here acts only as a fallback -->
    <input type="number" min="12" max="120" step="1" id="n1" name="age" pattern="\d+">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="t1">What's your favorite fruit?<abbr title="This field is mandatory">*</abbr></label>
    <input type="text" id="t1" name="fruit" list="l1" required pattern="[Bb]anana|[Cc]herry|[Aa]pple|[Ss]trawberry|[Ll]emon|[Oo]range">
    <datalist id="l1">
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>Cherry</option>
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Strawberry</option>
      <option>Lemon</option>
      <option>Orange</option>
    </datalist>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="t2">What's your e-mail?</label>
    <input type="email" id="t2" name="email">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="t3">Leave a short message</label>
    <textarea id="t3" name="msg" maxlength="140" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
```